# WCF service host in IIS 7.0 with svcutil.exe

Tags: c#, wcf

After host my service in Host I want to svcutil.exe will be                         `http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite/eval.svc?wsdl`

but when i view my service svcutil.exe created is following link:

```
http://win-ea8mlbabe9t/evalservicesite/eval.svc?wsdl
```

How can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

- Apply the Namespace property to the ServiceContractAttribute on the service contract interface
- Apply the Namespace property to the ServiceBehaviorAttribute on the class that implements the service
- Apply the Namespace property to the DataContractAttribute on every class that is involved with the service (parameters, return values)
- Change the namespace for the binding, either on the binding class or in the .config file

---

**Details :**

```
[ServiceContract ( Namespace = "http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite" )]
public interface I ...
{
```

&

```
[ServiceBehavior ( Namespace = "http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite" )]
public class ... : I ...
{
```

&

```
[DataContract ( Namespace = "http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite" )]
public class ...
{
```

&

```
< services >
    < service ... >
        < endpoint ... bindingNamespace="http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite" />
    </ service >
</ services >
```