# WCF Service Config file for IIS 7.0 Hosting

Tags: c#, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF service host in IIS 7.0 with svcutil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877228/wcf-service-host-in-iis-7-0-with-svcutil-exe)

I am new in WCF Service? I make a WCF Service that run successfully in Local host. But I can't able to host it IIS Server because of Configuration problem any one help me by giving complete example of config file for WCF Service host.

Note : My service name is "EvalService"
       My Site name is "EvalServiceSite"
I want to host my service with My existing Website Namely : "www.esimsol.com" 
With http://www.esimsol.com/evalservicesite/eval.svc

Thanks for response

Comment: What kind of configuration problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using svcutil to generate the appropriate config file.

you have to rename the app.config file that you get, to "web.config" in order to add it to IIS.

There is a good intro to what you want to do here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx